# missing windows/system32/config/system

Tags: windows-registry

i know it is common problem,
but not its so strange.

problem:
common missing windows/system32/config/system

what i do next:
put hdd to another pc and boot from it, it is succeeded but without warning window after startup that says like "windows has recovered from serious problem".
and than i put back hdd to previous pc.
tadaaa!!!!

missing windows/system32/config/system is happening again!
now i am trying repair this problem with recovery console from CD.
i hope it will successful.

someone can explain this?
what should i do?

Comment: My guess your system is infected with malware.  System files just don't go missing.  At the very least your hdd is failing and thats the resaon files are being deleted.

Comment: oho,i have forgot about virus.
i will check it then.

Comment: its not about virus.
i will post the answer 8 hours again,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem may caused by faulty RAM. Here there were two slots and I needed to test both.

You may get results like the following:

- First RAM is **good**
- Second RAM is **bad**

Taking both out and then putting the good RAM back in there was no error.

Put the other one in instead, or mix both, the error returns. This helps confirm that one of the RAM chips is faulty.

Testing this on another working hard drive using the same operating system showed the same error, confirming the RAM as the fault.